# How to create a "Not Having" SQL command

Tags: sql, ms-access

From MS Access query designer, I build a working query so far.

New requirements comes in where the results of the query needs to be filter further.

```
SELECT Sum(0) AS [#], Contacts.COMPANY, Proposals.[PROP NAME], Projects.[START DATE], Projects.DESCRIPTION, Projects.[TOTAL FEE], Projects.[PROJ ID], Contacts.[FULL NAME], Projects.COUNTRY
FROM (Contacts INNER JOIN Proposals ON Contacts.[CON ID] = Proposals.[CON ID]) INNER JOIN Projects ON Proposals.[PROP ID] = Projects.[PROP ID]
GROUP BY Contacts.COMPANY, Proposals.[PROP NAME], Projects.[START DATE], Projects.DESCRIPTION, Projects.[TOTAL FEE], Projects.[PROJ ID], Contacts.[FULL NAME], Projects.COUNTRY, Projects.[PROJECT STATUS]
HAVING ((((Proposals.[PROP NAME]) Like "*" & [forms]![TempUI]![SrchText] & "*") ) AND ((Projects.[START DATE]) Between [Forms]![TempUI]![txtRptDateStart] And [Forms]![TempUI]![txtRptDateEnd]) AND ((Projects.[PROJECT STATUS]) Like [forms]![TempUI]![cmb_scope]));
```

This query will filter the records based on the content of srchtxt (textbox)

Let's assume the result when srchtxt contain the word "fire" are these

```
Prop Name
----------
Fire Pump repair
Fire damage repair
Wall restructure due to building fire
Fire water pump
Roof repair due to fire
```

Now I need to further filter this to exclude the word "pump" because fire pump is a machine and has nothing to do with structures getting damage due to fire

I tried using `AND` `NOT LIKE` like this

```
HAVING ((((Proposals.[PROP NAME]) Like "*" & [forms]![TempUI]![SrchText] & "*") AND ((Proposals.[PROP NAME]) NOT LIKE [forms]![TempUI]![txtRPTexlude])) AND ((Projects.[START DATE]) Between [Forms]![TempUI]![txtRptDateStart] And [Forms]![TempUI]![txtRptDateEnd]) AND ((Projects.[PROJECT STATUS]) Like [forms]![TempUI]![cmb_scope]));
```

But it return no results.

Any idea what is the proper HAVING clause to exclude from results all records with the word "pump"?

Thanks

Comment: perhaps it's because of missing mask? `HAVING ((((Proposals.[PROP NAME]) Like "*" & [forms]![TempUI]![SrchText] & "*") AND ((Proposals.[PROP NAME]) NOT LIKE "*" & [forms]![TempUI]![txtRPTexlude] & "*")) AND ((Projects.[START DATE]) Between [Forms]![TempUI]![txtRptDateStart] And [Forms]![TempUI]![txtRptDateEnd]) AND ((Projects.[PROJECT STATUS]) Like "*" & [forms]![TempUI]![cmb_scope] & "*"));`

Comment: still having empty result

Comment: All of your `having` clauses should actually be in `where` clauses... `Having` is for applying conditions to the aggregated value.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a "not having" clause but you can still try to use a non exists coniditon

```
SELECT Whatever FROM wherever
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    *Select here*
)
```